# MySQL - How come I get 0 rows when I compare 2 tables when 1 of them return null?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables

Table 1 tbl1

```
ID | Name
1  | stack
```

Table 2 tbl2 (empty table)

```
ID | Name
```

I have this query

```
SELECT id FROM tbl1 WHERE id != (SELECT id FROM tbl2)
```

My subquery returns null which means the WHERE comparison is id != null and since my id = 1, shouldn't it display the id 1?

However I keep getting zero or no rows returns. Why is that?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to select rows from tbl1 where the id is not in tbl2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really don't know, but have you tried `SELECT id FROM tbl1 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM tbl2)`

Comment: Thanks! It's returning a value now.

Answer (score 2):

comparision to `null` will always result in `unknown`

if you want to see if something is `null` you have to use the `is` operator.

Comment: Thanks for explaining why its returning null

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the desired result, try using:

```
SELECT id FROM tbl1 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM tbl2);
```

As your initial query will be valid only when `tbl2` contains precisely 1 record.

`NULL` is a special value, you should use `value IS NULL` or `value IS NOT NULL` when checking for it.

Answer (score 0):

Subselects have the potential to be very expensive, try using this left join instead

```
SELECT tbl1.id FROM tbl1 LEFT JOIN tbl2 ON tbl2.id = tbl1.id WHERE tbl2.id IS NULL
```

Comment: You need `SELECT tbl1.id ...`

Comment: A nice reading about (wrong assumptions and) performance: [NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL: MySQL](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/)

Comment: That's a huge generalization, being that the true performance of this subselect depends on your optimizations, your index, your database engine, the amount of records you truly have, etc... 9 times of out 10 in my production environment with over 4 million records of live data, left joins have proven to be more efficient again and again

Comment: Off course it is a generalization and one should always test with his data, engine, etc... Your statement *"Subselects have the potential to be very expensive"* is a generalization, too.